# Line break after command, before period

Tags: macros, line-breaking

This is the output of `pdflatex`:
[image: PDF snapshot]

The relevant LaTeX line is:

```
You can similarly enable the third and fourth channel by giving \texttt{HIGH} input to \icpin{9}{EN3,4}.
```

Here is how I defined the `\icpin` command:

```
\newcommand{\icpin}[2]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} \fbox{\texttt{\colorbox{lgray}{\strut{}\,PIN~#1\,}\,#2\,}} \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}
```

I guess the problem is in the command I defined. How do I force the line break not to come just before a period?

I tried using `\@` after the period, did not solve the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Try removing  the space before `\setlength`.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  Oh, you also have a `\,` at the end which probably needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you give has two spaces that you should remove

```
\newcommand{\icpin}[2]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} \fbox{\texttt{\colorbox{lgray}{\strut{}\,PIN~#1\,}\,#2\,}} \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}}
                                                ^                                                          ^
```

Here's a properly formatted one, with some changes:

```
\newcommand{\icpin}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fbox{%
    \ttfamily
    \colorbox{lgray}{\strut\,PIN~#1\,}\,#2\,%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
```

The group makes the settIng to `\fboxsep` local to it, so you don't need to explicitly reset it. Using `\ttfamily` avoids a further pair of braces: the group will limit the effect of this declaration.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{lgray}{gray}{0.7}

\newcommand{\icpin}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fbox{%
    \ttfamily
    \colorbox{lgray}{\strut\,PIN~#1\,}\,#2\,%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

You can similarly enable the third and fourth channel
by giving \texttt{HIGH} input to \icpin{9}{EN3,4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you should add also thin spaces at either end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{lgray}{gray}{0.7}

\newcommand{\icpin}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \leavevmode\,% <-- don't forget \leavevmode
  \fbox{%
    \ttfamily
    \colorbox{lgray}{\strut\,PIN~#1\,}\,#2\,%
  }%
  \,%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

You can similarly enable the third and fourth channel
by giving \texttt{HIGH} input to \icpin{9}{EN3,4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `\,` and the extra spaces seems to make the period attached to the box.  Here is a *beofre* and *after* image:

[image]

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\icpin}[2]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \fbox{\texttt{\colorbox{gray}{\strut{}\,PIN~#1\,}\,#2}}%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}%
}%

\begin{document}
You can similarly enable the third and fourth channel by giving \texttt{HIGH} input to \icpin{9}{EN3,4}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Removing the last `\,` was not necessary, removing the spaces solved the problem.