# How to avoid linebreak after command and before period?

Tags: xetex, line-breaking

I use XeLaTeX with the memoir class to typeset my linguistics thesis. In the running text, I often mention prefixes, which have a following hyphen. For example: "*un-* is an inherited Germanic negation prefix".

Now, sometimes this prefix will be before a comma, or at the end of a sentence.
And sometimes, LaTeX will insert a linebreak after the hyphen, but before the period.
Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
openright,
oneside,
12pt,
]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}
\noindent In (6.269), the first person pronoun \textit{wɨ} co-occurs with the coreferential bound marker \textit{j-}.
For Wayana, Tavares (2005: 413) states that first and second person pronouns cannot occur in P position.
\end{document}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Now, I don't understand why LaTeX would allow a period at the start of the beginning.
The OP of [How to avoid a linebreak before a comma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29884/how-to-avoid-a-linebreak-before-a-comma) was also wondering that, but no satisfying solution was found there.
I have also seen [Line break after command, before period](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321299/line-break-after-command-before-period), which features a non-basic custom command.

Any ideas?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use an en dash – instead of a hyphen -. I actually prefer that for citation forms of morphemes.

Comment: While this might be a solution for some individual cases, it is not a general solution. In my specific MWE, it does not work -- the only difference is the length of the line, but the linebreak is the same!

Comment: It certainly works for me with your MWE as posted.

Comment: For me, this code does not work, and I think I've used a standard en-dash?

`
\documentclass[a4paper,
openright,
oneside,
12pt,
]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}
\noindent In (6.269), the first person pronoun \textit{wɨ} co-occurs with the coreferential bound marker \textit{j–}.
For Wayana, Tavares (2005: 413) states that first and second person pronouns cannot occur in P position.
\end{document}
`

Comment: You mean you still get the linebreak after the en dash?

Comment: Yes! [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/xpS0qDJ) with hyphen and en dash compared.

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because TeX  thinks a that a hyphen is always a good place to break a line. It doesn't really know about the beginning of the line, in the sense that it can avoid putting a `.` there. So a word that ends with hyphen will always potentially pose this problem.

You can use the solution adopted by the `ngerman` language definition file to create a non-breaking hyphen as discussed in the first question you link to [How to avoid a linebreak before a comma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29884/how-to-avoid-a-linebreak-before-a-comma). Here I've just made a `\nbhyphen` command to introduce a no-break hyphen. Alternatively, you could define a `\prefix` macro which would add the hyphen automatically. I've replaced your `\textit` with `\emph` since you want the formatting of words/morphemes to revert automatically to upright if they are themselves embedded in `\emph`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
openright,
oneside,
12pt,
]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % for textormath macro
\usepackage{geometry}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\providecommand{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#1}
\newcommand\nbhyphen
{%
  \texorpdfstring{\textormath{\leavevmode\hbox{-}}{-}}% tex string
                 {-}% PDF string
}
\newcommand\prefix[1]{#1\nbhyphen}

\begin{document}


% use \nbhyphen
\noindent In (6.269), the first person pronoun \emph{wɨ} co-occurs with the coreferential bound marker \emph{j\nbhyphen}.
For Wayana, Tavares (2005: 413) states that first and second person pronouns cannot occur in P position.

% alternate syntax: make a command for prefix
\noindent In (6.269), the first person pronoun \emph{wɨ} co-occurs with the coreferential bound marker \emph{\prefix{j}}.
For Wayana, Tavares (2005: 413) states that first and second person pronouns cannot occur in P position.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

If `luatex` with `babel` is an option, you can use the tools provided by the latter to deal with special hyphenation cases. In this particular case, the following should work:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\babelposthyphenation{english}{={.}} % (1)
 { { pre = -, no= -, penalty = 10000 },  % (2)
   {}, % (3)
 }
```

The pattern (1) means ‘explicit hyphen followed by a dot’ (the braces around the dot prevent it from being interpreted as ‘any character’, as customary in regexps). The second argument reinserts the explicit hyphen with a penalty (2), and then retains the second char (the dot, 3). See [Non–standard hyphenation with luatex](https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/Non%E2%80%93standard-hyphenation-with-luatex).

Answer (score 0):

If you frequently show prefixes, it's better to define a suitable command for them, so you can decide even at the last moment how to print them.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  openright,
  oneside,
  12pt,
]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand{\prefix}[1]{\mbox{\textit{#1-}}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Original}

\noindent In (6.269), the first person pronoun \textit{wɨ} co-occurs with
the coreferential bound marker \textit{j-}. For Wayana, Tavares (2005: 413)
states that first and second person pronouns cannot occur in P position.


\subsubsection*{With macro}

\noindent In (6.269), the first person pronoun \textit{wɨ} co-occurs with 
the coreferential bound marker \prefix{j}. For Wayana, Tavares~(2005:~413) 
states that first and second person pronouns cannot occur in P~position.

\end{document}
```

Note the ties I inserted in order to avoid possible bad breaks.

[image]